# Asp.net MVC Oauth session expiring quickly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, oauth

I am learning open authentication in asp.net MVC app. 
Login via **Facebook**, **google** working fine but on deployment the session is expiring quickly. Mostly due to application pool recycle. In my local system working fine.

I faced the same issue earlier with form authentication, by changing session state mode to "state server" from "in proc" worked for it. How to do same for open auth?

I have set high values for session timeout like

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },
                ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 2, 30),
                SlidingExpiration = true
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

in many cases, Shared Web Servers do not allow long session expiration times! have you tried saving [sessions in SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104082/Configuring-ASP-session-state-on-SQL-server)?

Comment: Thanks. That's true, but the question is about authentication info not about session. Session is fine.

Comment: I guessed you were talking about session timeout on server and high values not working.. actually you didn't mention _authentication info_. @Satyajit